# What to do when converting infix to postfix expression using stack?

Tags: data-structures, stack

Problem I am facing is that what to do when two operators of same priorities are their?
Example:
If ^ is in the top of stack and ^ comes that what to do?
Should I enter it in stack or just pop out one ^ or both ^ comes out of the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Since both operators are of same precedence, it doesn't matter in which order you execute the calculation as long as there is no bracket involved. You can push it onto stack and do calculation later together or pop the existing one to do the calculation now.

Answer (score 0):

What to do in this case depends on the operator or its specific precedence level, and is referred to as the operator's associativity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Usually **+** and **-** have the same precedence and left associativity, for example, meaning **a+b-c+d = ((a+b)-c)+d**.

The assignment operators usually have right-associativity, meaning **a=b+=c=d** is the same as **a=(b+=(c=d))**

I haven't done a detailed survey, but I think that exponentiation operators usually have right associativity, because left associativity is redundant with multiplication, i.e., **(a^b)^c = a^(b*c)**